# Music Player "easy" Div prob

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I just downloaded music player for my website here:
http://www.codebasehero.com/2011/06/html-music-player/

But the div don't display in my block.

For example, I put the script between two div's but the script create his own div after all of MY div's.

```
<?php include('entete-player.php'); ?>
  <div id="CONTENT">
    <h1>Connexion</h1>
    <div id="TEXT">
      <script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(function(){
              var description = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.   Fusce id tortor nisi. Aenean sodales diam ac lacus elementum scelerisque. Suspendisse a dui   vitae lacus faucibus venenatis vel id nisl. Proin orci ante, ultricies nec interdum at,     iaculis venenatis nulla. ';
              $('body').ttwMusicPlayer(myPlaylist, {
                  autoPlay:false, 
                  description:description,
                  jPlayer:{
                      swfPath:'player/plugin/jquery-jplayer' //You need to override the   default swf path any time the directory structure changes
                  }
              });
          });
      </script>
    </div>
  </div>
<?php include ('pied.php'); ?>
```

This is my header,

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Under Shift - Site Officiel</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<link href="images/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="icon" href="images/favicon.ico" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="player/plugin/css/style.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="player/demo/css/demo.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="player/demo/js/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="player/plugin/jquery-jplayer/jquery.jplayer.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="player/plugin/ttw-music-player-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="player/demo/js/myplaylist.js"></script>
</head>
```

This is what I see in Dev console:

```
<html></html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div id="HEADER">...</div>
<div id="CONTENT">...</div>
<div id="FOOTER">...</div>
<div id="pluginInstalledv2">...</div>
<div class="ttw-music-player" style="opacity: 1;">...</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is what I want:

```
<html></html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div id="HEADER">...</div>
<div id="CONTENT">
<div id="pluginInstalledv2">...</div>
<div class="ttw-music-player" style="opacity: 1;">...</div>
</div>
<div id="FOOTER">...</div>    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you included the jQuery library above in the head? and another thing seems to me there should be some error about `myPlaylist`. if you could post the error if you have in your browser's console.

Comment: I edited the main messsage. You should understand now. Thank you Jai.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get it to appear the way you want it (in the code atleast), in the javascript(jQuery) above, theres a line that looks like this

```
 $('body').ttwMusicPlayer(myPlaylist, {
```

Change that to

```
 $('#pluginInstalledv2').ttwMusicPlayer(myPlaylist, {
```

This will get the player to appear where you want it in the code atleast. Then from there, you style as needed for positioning or whatever else.

edit***
to better explain, that line, where it says "body" is telling that script to load the player anywhere in the body pretty much.

When you change "body" to "pluginInstalledv2" which is the name i assume where you want the player to be, it places the player inside that div.

all you need to do after that is style it and thats it.

good luck and hope this works for you.